# Western digital HD WD5000AAJS keeps suspending

Tags: hard-drive, suspend

I have a 500Gb Western Digital HD WD5000AAJS (ZZYFA0) which keeps to suspend very frequently.

When I access it after a couple of minutes I need to wait for it to spin up again.

I'm using Win7 64bit, I disabled HD suspension, I tried to disable the head parking with WDIDLE but it told me that it was already disabled.

None of the solutions I tried, worked.

Regards.

Comment: It sounds like this is one of those Western Digital "Green" drives can you confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's "suspending", I think the term you're looking for is "spin down". There are various solutions suggested from googling, from disabling SMART in the BIOS, disabling "turn off hard disks" in Windows power management, to "you can't".